# JavaScript redirect - replacing `&` with `&amp;amp`

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to redirect to a new page using JavaScript. I need to redirect to page:

**DESIRED LINK where to redirect**:
`http://localhost/mypage.html?myparam1=A&myparam2=B`

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**:
Javascript code to redirect page to desired URL:
`window.location.assign('http://localhost/mypage.html?myparam1=A&myparam2=B');`

**Result**:

Unfortunately, all `&` were replaced by `&amp;amp;` as shown here:

`http://localhost/mypage.html?myparam1=A&amp;myparam2=B`

Which cannot be parsed properly by underlying server (Java & Thymeleaf),
and unfortunately it does not work when parsed by J2EE.

**How can I force to redirect to a page without replacing `&` with `&amp;amp`?**

Comment: The code you have will not transform `&` into `&amp;` that must be done by something else on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use assign for redirect ? Use simply window.location.href like you previous code.

Another do you try to escape & char ?
Do you use XSS prenvent function in your code ?